# Create Json X,Y structure

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to create the below structure:

```
"chartData": [
                    {
                        label: "Your group",
                        data: [
                            [-2, 10],
                            [2, 20],
                            [-1, 11],
                            [-1, -12],
                            [-1, 5]
                        ],
                        info: [
                            {
                                id: "a1"
                            },
                            {
                                id: "b1"
                            },
                            {
                                id: "c1"
                            },
                            {
                                id: "d1"
                            },
                            {
                                id: "e1"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
```

everything is fine other than the data section. If I create a class to represent each data point, with for example a property for X and a property for Y then the JSON created will look something like this:

```
 "chartData": [
                        {
                            label: "Your group",
                            data: [
                                {X=-2, Y=10},
                                {X=-5, Y=17},
                                {X=-1, Y=13},
                                {X=-8, Y=8},
                                {X=-5, Y=13}
                            ],
                            info: [
                                {
                                    id: "a1"
                                },
                                {
                                    id: "b1"
                                },
                                {
                                    id: "c1"
                                },
                                {
                                    id: "d1"
                                },
                                {
                                    id: "e1"
                                }
```

Defining the data type to be a double[,] also doesn't create the same format.
I need to stick to this format as it at the request of an external vendor that the data looks like this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinate pairs need to be an array of `int` or `double`.

```
class ChartData {
    string label;
    int[][] data;
    Info[] info;
}
```

`data` should be initialized like this:

```
var cd = new ChartData();
cd.data = new int[100][];
```

And, each point should be something like:

```
cd.data[0] = new[] { 1, 1 };
cd.data[1] = new[] { -10, 50};
//etc
```

Comment: Thanks for you speedy reply